# curl don't follow location after post

Tags: curl

I have a REST API with the follow endpoint:

```
curl -L -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d "{\"source\" : \"3\", \"destination\" : \"5\"}" "http://localhost:8080/api/edge" |cjson
```

This request don't render the location URL after post (return null, in this case, I am using `cjson` for format output). If I use a tool like `postman` after the post the correct redirect is done.

here using the `-i` option:

```
curl -i -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d "{\"source\" : \"3\", \"destination\" : \"5\"}" "http://localhost:8080/api/edge"

HTTP/1.1 303 See Other
Date: Sun, 27 Sep 2015 01:39:40 GMT
Location: http://localhost:8080/api/customer
Vary: Accept
Content-Type: application/json;charset=ISO-8859-1
Content-Length: 0
Server: Jetty(7.6.8.v20121106)
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `-post303` option to make sure that after getting a HTTP 303 response on a POST message, it will use POST again when it follows the redirect, so:

```
curl -L -post303 -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d "{\"source\" : \"3\", \"destination\" : \"5\"}" "http://localhost:8080/api/edge" |cjson
```